# Getting "Request path contains unescaped characters error" while doing a post request in Node Js

Tags: node.js, request, httpclient

Trying to make a POST request through proxy, getting an error like unescaped charcters in the request. But this works fine without proxy.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
            url: "https://sezion.com/api?accountID=58340ff7c05c1c8dac59e895&accountSecret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=",
            proxy: "http://proxy.example.com:8989",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"zdoLXrB5IkwQzwV2wBoj","method":"barrister-idl","params":[]}',
            json:true
}, function(error, response, body){
console.log(error);
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  console.log(body);
});
```

While running this code, getting an error like,

```
_http_client.js:53
    throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters');
    ^

TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:53:11)
    at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (D:\Seizon\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:117:25)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (D:\Seizon\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:189:41)
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (D:\Seizon\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:81:8)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:158:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:199:15)
    at Request.start (D:\Seizon\node_modules\request\main.js:428:30)
    at Request.write (D:\Seizon\node_modules\request\main.js:812:28)
```

Comment: I also have this problem on Sandstorm developing. Can I get the real path with problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = require('request');
var qs = require('querystring');

var url = "https://sezion.com/api?" +
    qs.stringify({
        accountID: '58340ff7c05c1c8dac59e895',
        accountSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx='
    });
request.post({
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "zdoLXrB5IkwQzwV2wBoj", "method": "barrister-idl", "params": [] },
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Thnks, but the code works very fine without proxy...Even this isnt worrking

Comment: @siddiqrehman try again, tested work, with your real accountSecret, anyway is best practice to stringify/escape your querystring